# Markdown error rendering URL?

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, markdown-preview, markdown-rendering

Here's a URL:

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm

On my screen (Chrome browser, Mac OS X, up to date), it reads this way, both in the live preview and once actually posted:

.htm">http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp_.htm

If you look at the source of what I've posted, each line above which contains a link is the same except that the second prepends the following: .htm"> - that is, I have literally added this "garbage" to the front on the second example, but on my screen both lines look the same once previewed or posted--apart from the fact that only the second one (which is written "stupidly" to demonstrate the problem) is actually clickable--the first link is not clickable.

If I have to include a question here, it would be: does this reproduce for others?  How can we fix it?

Answer (score 5):

As a work around, you can use either the full form or footnote styles of anchors:

```
[http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm](http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm)

[http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm][1]
```

Either of them will render correctly.

Footnote style:

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm

Full:

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm

You can also use the formal Markdown syntax for specifying a bare link, or escape one of the underscores:

```
<http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm>

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp_\_.htm
```

Formal bare link style:

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm

Escaped underscore:

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp__.htm